# Why we use get() method after Weak Reference Object Instances (Like Text View)?

Tags: java, android, weak-references

Why we use get() method after WeakReference Text View Instance?

```
private WeakReference<TextView> mTitleText;
private TextView mAuthorText;

FetchBook(TextView titleText, TextView authorText) {
    this.mTitleText = new WeakReference<>(titleText);
    this.mAuthorText = authorText;

    //in weakPreference Text View
    mTitleText.get().setText("hello");

    //in standard text view 
    authorText.setText("by by ");
}
```

why we can not set the text of textView straightly in weak reference without `get()` method?

Comment: Cause `WeakReference` is a Generic class which can hold any Object. when you call `#get()` on it, it  will return the saved object .

Comment: Your welcome .. I think the answer below by Sweeper is pretty well explained. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because as far as the compiler is concerned, the type `WeakReference<TextView>` is completely unrelated to `TextView`. `WeakReference` is a totally different class from `TextView`.

Consider this code:

```
Foo<T> {
    private T bar;
    public T get() { return bar; }

    public Foo(T bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

class Bar {
    public void func() {}
}
...
Foo<Bar> foo = new Foo(new Bar());
```

You are basically asking

> Why can't I call `foo.func()` directly? Why do I have to call `foo.get().func()`?

Because `func` is declared in `Bar`, not in `Foo`. And `foo.get()` returns an instance of `Bar`, which you can use to call `func`.

`setText` is declared in `TextView`, not in `WeakReference`. `WeakReference.get` gives you an instance of `TextView`, which you can use to call `setText`.